# Representation of $S_n$ by $V^{\otimes n}$,

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a real and finite dimensional vectorspace. Then
$$
\sigma.(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n) := (-1)^{\sigma} v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}.
$$
My question: Why is this action on $V^{\otimes n}$ a representation of $S_n$ ? How do I check this ?

Comment: I have no knowledge of representation theory. After reading about it on Wikipedia, it seems that it should be an action which preserves the linear structure (like scalar multiplication, addition, etc ), which I think is clear.

Comment: I am confused about the tensor product. I.e. how do I show that $\sigma.(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n + w_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes w_n) = \sigma.( \cdots) + \sigma.(\cdots)$.

Comment: That's by definition. What you need to do is see that it is still well-defined with this linearity condition imposed - i.e. you need to verify that it acts as expected whenever a pure tensor can be written as a sum of pure tensors.

Comment: Also, you have defined a *right* action of $S_n$. You need $\sigma^{-1}$ in the subscripts to be a left action. (This seems counterintuitive to a lot of people at first.)

Comment: I think the big problem you need to understand is how to *construct* linear maps on a tensor product space. If you can't do that then you're not really going to understand how to show a formula given only on elementary tensors really does extend to a linear map on the whole tensor product space. Do you know how to *construct* a linear map $V \otimes_K W \rightarrow U$ for $K$-vector spaces $V$, $W$, and $U$?

Comment: That is indeed the problem. I think I first have to get into this.

Comment: Ok. As far as I understand I must check that the for given $\sigma$ the map $(v_1,v_2) \mapsto \sigma.(v_1 \otimes v_2)$ bilineair is. (if $n = 2$ and then multilineair for bigger $n$). This seems to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that an explicit example might be helpful.  Let's look at $n = 3$.  I will write the elements of $S_3$ in cycle notation:
$$
S_3 = \{ 1, \underbrace{(12), (13), (23)}_{\text{transpositions}}, \underbrace{(123), (132)}_{3-\text{cycles}} \}.
$$
Let's fix the dimension of the underlying vector space as well.  Say, $\dim V = 3$ with basis $\{ v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$.  Now, $S_3$ will act on the $3$-fold tensor product:  $V^{\otimes 3} = V \otimes V \otimes V$, which has dimension $3^3 = 27$ and basis:
$$
\left\{\begin{align}
v_1 \otimes &v_1 \otimes v_1 \\
v_1 \otimes &v_1 \otimes v_2 \\
v_1 \otimes &v_1 \otimes v_3 \\
v_1 \otimes &v_2 \otimes v_1 \\
v_1 \otimes &v_2 \otimes v_2 \\
&\vdots \\
v_3 \otimes &v_3 \otimes v_2 \\
v_3 \otimes &v_3 \otimes v_3
\end{align}\right\}.
$$
The representation can be thought of as a group homomorphism $S_3 \to GL(V^{\otimes 3})$, so we can associate a $27 \times 27$ matrix to each permutation, by using the given ordered basis.

As mentioned in the comments, in order to act on the left (write your functions on the left), you have to use the inverse of each permutation.  Study the following calculation to see why.
$$
v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes v_3 \mathrel{\mathop{\mapsto}^{(12)}} - v_2 \otimes v_1 \otimes v_3 \mathrel{\mathop{\mapsto}^{(23)}} v_2 \otimes v_3 \otimes v_1
$$
Now, $(23)(12) = (132)$ in $S_3$, and
$$
v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes v_3 \mathrel{\mathop{\mapsto}^{(132)}} v_2 \otimes v_3 \otimes v_1
$$
only if the permutation acts by its inverse.  Here's the general calculation which uses the fact that the sign $\sigma \mapsto (-1)^{\sigma}$ is a group homomorphism.

$$
\begin{align}
(\sigma \tau).(v_{i_1} \otimes v_{i_2} \otimes v_{i_3}) &= (-1)^{\sigma \tau} v_{(\sigma \tau)^{-1}(i_1)} \otimes v_{(\sigma \tau)^{-1}(i_2)} \otimes v_{(\sigma \tau)^{-1}(i_3)} \\
&= (-1)^{\sigma} (-1)^{\tau} v_{\tau^{-1} (\sigma^{-1}(i_1))} \otimes v_{\tau^{-1} (\sigma^{-1}(i_2))} \otimes v_{\tau^{-1} (\sigma^{-1}(i_3))} \\
&= \tau.((-1)^{\sigma} v_{\sigma^{-1}(i_1)} \otimes v_{\sigma^{-1}(i_2)} \otimes v_{\sigma^{-1}(i_3)}) \\
&= \sigma.(\tau.(v_{i_1} \otimes v_{i_2} \otimes v_{i_3}))
\end{align}
$$

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Now I also understand where the $\sigma^{-1}$ comes from.

Comment: I dont get the last line of you equations: I think $\sigma.(\tau.(v_1,\cdots,v_n)) = \sigma.((-1)^\tau v_{\tau^{-1}(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\tau^{-1}(n)}) = (-1)^\sigma (-1)^\tau v_{\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}(n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

This action on $V^{\otimes n}$ gives a homomorphism from $S_n$ to the automorphism group of $V^{\otimes n}$.

Define $$\phi : S_{n} \to \text{Aut}(V^{\otimes n})$$ $$\phi(\sigma)\biggl(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n\biggr) := (-1)^{\sigma} v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$$

and then extend $\phi(\sigma)$ by linearity.

Then you have to check that $\phi(\lambda \sigma) = \phi(\lambda) \cdot \phi(\sigma)$ and that each $\phi(\sigma)$ is bijective.

Comment: You cannot define $\phi:S_n\to Aut(V^{\otimes n})$ and **then** extend by linearity.

Answer (score 1):

- Let $\sigma$ be an element of $S_n$. There is a function $$m_\sigma:\underbrace{V\times\cdots\times V}_{\text{$n$ factors}}\to V^{\otimes n}$$ such that for all $v_1$, $\dots$, $v_n\in V$, $$m_\sigma(v_1,\dots,v_n)=(-1)^{\operatorname{sgn}\sigma} v_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}.$$ You can check that $m_\sigma$ is $n$-multilinear, so it induces a linear map $\bar m_\sigma:V^{\otimes n}\to V^{\otimes n}$.
- Next, you can check that if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are elements of $S_n$, then $\bar m_\sigma\circ\bar m_\tau=\bar m_{\sigma\tau}$, and that if $e$ is the identity element in $S_n$, then $\bar m_{e}$ is the identity map of $V^{\otimes n}$.
- Using that, you can check that the linear maps $\bar m_{\sigma}$ and $\bar m_{\sigma^{-1}}$, both $V^{\otimes n}\to V^{\otimes n}$, are mutually inverse.
- It follows from this that we have a function $\rho:\sigma\in S_n\mapsto\bar m_{\sigma}\in\operatorname{Aut}(V^{\otimes n})$. Now it is easy to show that this function is even a group homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Once you see that this determines a linear map $U(\sigma)$ from $V^{\otimes n}$ to itself, all you have to verify is that $\sigma \to U(\sigma)$ is a homomorphism, i.e. that $U(\sigma \tau) = U(\sigma) U(\tau)$ for permutations $\sigma$ and $\tau$.

Comment: I am confused about the $V^{\otimes n}$. How do I check for example that the map is linear ?